# Removing padding from structure in kernel module

Tags: gcc, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module, packing

I am compiling a kernel module, containing a structure of size 34, using the standard command.

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

The `sizeof(some_structure)` is coming as 36 instead of 34 i.e. the compiler is padding the structure.

How do I remove this padding?

Running `make V=1` shows the gcc compiler options passed as

```
make -I../inc -C /lib/modules/2.6.29.4-167.fc11.i686.PAE/build M=/home/vishal/20100426_eth_vishal/organised_eth/src modules

make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.29.4-167.fc11.i686.PAE'
test -e include/linux/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (  \
 echo;        \
 echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";  \
 echo "         include/linux/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing."; \
 echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it."; \
 echo;        \
 /bin/false)

mkdir -p /home/vishal/20100426_eth_vishal/organised_eth/src/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/vishal/20100426_eth_vishal/organised_eth/src/.tmp_versions/*

make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/vishal/20100426_eth_vishal/organised_eth/src

  gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/vishal/20100426_eth_vishal/organised_eth/src/.eth_main.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.0/include -Iinclude  -I/usr/src/kernels/2.6.29.4-167.fc11.i686.PAE/arch/x86/include -include include/linux/autoconf.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Os -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Iarch/x86/include/asm/mach-generic -Iarch/x86/include/asm/mach-default -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-stack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fwrapv -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm -DTX_DESCRIPTOR_IN_SYSTEM_MEMORY -DRX_DESCRIPTOR_IN_SYSTEM_MEMORY -DTX_BUFFER_IN_SYSTEM_MEMORY -DRX_BUFFER_IN_SYSTEM_MEMORY -DALTERNATE_DESCRIPTORS -DEXT_8_BYTE_DESCRIPTOR -O0 -Wall -DT_ETH_1588_051 -DALTERNATE_DESCRIPTORS -DEXT_8_BYTE_DESCRIPTOR -DNETHERNET_INTERRUPTS -DETH_IEEE1588_TESTS -DSNAPTYPSEL_TMSTRENA_TEVENTENA_TESTS -DT_ETH_1588_140_147 -DLOW_DEBUG_PRINTS -DMEDIUM_DEBUG_PRINTS -DHIGH_DEBUG_PRINTS -DMODULE -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(eth_main)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(conxt_eth)"  -c -o /home/vishal/20100426_eth_vishal/organised_eth/src/eth_main.o /home/vishal/20100426_eth_vishal/organised_eth/src/eth_main.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#pragma [pack](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) might work

Answer (score 5):

If using GCC, you can use the **packed** attribute on your structure to prevent padding:

```
struct foo
{
    void * bar;
}
__attribute__( ( packed ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that GCC is forcing the total structure to be aligned onto a 32 bit boundary, so its size is a multiple of 4.

Imagine the following.
struct foo
{

void * bar ;
 some other stuff .....
};

struct foo my_foo_array[10];

Then if the sizeof(struct foo) is not a multiple of 4 then.
my_foo_array[0].bar has a different memory alignment to my_foo_array[1].bar. The processor would need to perform 2 32 bit memory accesses  in order to access all four bytes of my_foo_array[1].bar. x86 processors will do this reassembly of misaligned 32 bit values but most other processors will throw some form of bus error exception which is not good.

The packed attribute signals how the elements of the structure are packed with respect to each other, but in normal operation the start of structure needs to placed on a 32 bit aligned address.

I hope this explains things a little better.

Comment: Hi Andrew,


GCC generates a 32 bit aligned address on x86 by default as it is optimum for x86 32 bit processor to fetch data. I only wanted to know how to solve to padding issue with GCC.
The pragma pack worked for me.